# Python script won't write data when ran from cron

Tags: python, scripts

When I run a python script in a terminal it runs as expected; downloads file and saves it in the desired spot.

```
sudo python script.py
```

I've added the python script to the root crontab, but then it runs as it is supposed to except it does not write the file.

```
$ sudo crontab -l
> * * * * * python /home/test/script.py >> /var/log/test.log 2>&1
```

Below is a simplified script that still has the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

scheduleUrl = 'http://test.com/schedule.xml'
schedule = '/var/test/schedule.xml'

# Download url and save as filename
def wget(url, filename):
    import urllib2
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        logging.exception('generic exception: ' + traceback.format_exc())
    else:
        print('writing:'+filename+';')
        output = open(filename,'wb')
        output.write(response.read())
        output.close()

# Download the schedule
wget(scheduleUrl, schedule)
```

I do get the message "writing:name of file;" inside the log, to which the cron entry outputs. But the actual file is nowhere to be found...

The dir /var/test is chmodded to 777 and using whatever user, I am allowed to add and change files as I please.

Comment: It is a rights issue. I figured out that when I have the files I want to write present and I chmod those to something like 666 then everything works fine.

So how to get python to be able to write as well? I thought by adding the script to the sudo crontab it would run with some priviledges I'd usually have when sudoing myself...

Comment: You can't **sudo** when you are not there.  This command gives you temporary elevated rights, predicated on entry of the required password.

Comment: david6, I thought that by adding it using sudo crontab filename.cron that the scripts would be executed as if executed using sudo. So with elevated rights. This is not correct?

Comment: The command **sudo crontab -l** will report your current crontab settings. The 'sudo' would NOT effect anything.  You would need to try something like using 'cron' (for root user) **[Not Recommended]** - you should instead be looking at: **chroot**.

Comment: david6; you are wrong. sudo crontab -l and crontab -l display different entries. And so far I'm not getting permission denieds for tasks in the sudo crontab on tasks that do display this message in the current user crontab.

Comment: Your script does not work: `NameError: global name 'logging' is not defined` on line 13.

Answer (score 5):

- Check log files `grep -i cron /var/log/syslog`
- Add an empty line to the end of the crontab, This has been a known bug for ages, not sure if it is solved.
- Remove the `2>&1` from the command line until it works as designed. Any usefull errors are redirected to a file that is not created; effectively lost.
- Check if root received mail (eg. using `mutt` or in `/var/spool/mail`). Error messages from cron are sent to system email by default.

Also:

- Reconsider the 777 permissions as soon as possible. When running from root, 755 root:root should be sufficient to be able to check the logs from unprivileged user)
- Reconsider running the script from root, it is bad practise.

Answer (score 1):

## What works for me

Crontab

```
#Borrowed from anacron
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
#End borrowed from anacron

* * * * *   python /home/username/somedir/test.py
```

Python script

```
scheduleUrl = 'http://example.com/index.html'
schedule = '/tmp/test.html'

# Download url and save as filename
def wget(url, filename):
    import urllib2
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except Exception:
        import logging
        logging.exception('error')
    else:
        print('writing:'+filename+';')
        output = open(filename,'wb')
        output.write(response.read())
        output.close()

# Download the schedule
wget(scheduleUrl, schedule)
```

Added environment variables.  Used tmp instead of var to verify there weren't permissions issues.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem:

```
f = open('./my_file.txt', 'w')
f.close()
```

Was not opening and writing the file when run from cron. This solved it

```
f = open('<full_path_of_file>/my_file.txt', 'w')
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks - would have never figured that out!

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was as simple as changing the file access mode.
Instead of:

```
output = open(filename,'wb')
```

Try:

```
output = open(filename,'rb+')
```

I used this to scrape craigslist for job postings (for myself) and to model into a database. All done on a raspberry pi.

I found this and it's very similar to the issue I was having, though I didn't quite get my answer from here. The cron job was executing but the python script would not write files when executed via a cron job. The script would write web scraped text files if executed from the command line.

Solution for me was simply the `wb` to `rb+`
`rb+`   Opens a file for both reading and writing in binary format. The file pointer placed at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Actually, my mistake. I changed to wb+ but the most import think is to use the absolute file path when saving the file.
file = open('absolute/path/to/file.txt', 'wb+')

Now things are working